# How to get MiniProfiler 4 logging to Serilog (or access within Middleware)?

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog, miniprofiler

I've been trying to get MiniProfiler.AspNetCore to work with Serilog.AspNetCore, or otherwise be able to log calls.

I tried creating a middleware with `EndInvoke` calling

```
private void EndInvoke(HttpContext context)
if (MiniProfiler.Current != null)
{
   Log.ForContext("MiniProfiler", JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(MiniProfiler.Current.ToJson()))
      .Verbose("Completed request in {Timing} ms", MiniProfiler.Current.DurationMilliseconds);
}
```

I'm trying to set it up similar to https://daveaglick.com/posts/easy-performance-and-query-logging-in-aspnet-with-serilog-and-miniprofiler which was done with the 3.0 not 4.0 version of MiniProfiler, as well as aspnet not aspnetcore.

Edit: Fixed the null issue, I was creating my middleware before the miniprofiler middleware, but it is still not logging to serilog/seq properly.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like part of the issue was I was missing

`destructureObjects: true` on the end of my `ForContext()` call

```
private void EndInvoke(HttpContext context)
{
    MiniProfiler.Current.Stop();
    if (MiniProfiler.Current != null)
    {
        Log.ForContext("MiniProfiler", JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(MiniProfiler.Current.ToJson()), destructureObjects: true)
            .Debug("Completed request in {Timing} ms", MiniProfiler.Current.DurationMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

And the main reason was... I was filtering out verbose calls from sending to my seq server... changing it to debug made them show up right away.

So hope this question might help someone else in the future, but this does work with `MiniProfiler 4` and `AspNetCore 2`. You will need `Destructurama.JsonNet` and add `.Destructure.JsonNetTypes()` on your `LoggerConfiguration()`, otherwise you'll just get empty items in your output.